# Attempted key copy leads to immobilizer activating

Tags: honda, immobilizer, theft-prevention

I attempted to get the key copy for my 2003 Honda Civic at Lowe's. They could not make a copy of it but now my car won't start due to the immobilizer being activated. Less than 15 minutes between trying to start it and the attempted copy.

what are my options?

Comment: How do you know it's the immobilizer which is causing the issues? You are using the original key? It obviously worked to get you to the store?

Comment: @paulster2 the immobilizer light was flashing, and the you could hear a relay click but nothing spun.